# TypeError: Cannot read property 'ng-leave' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been struggling with this for the last month, it is very weird, it goes away for a week and then comes back. I've been reading on what the people does to remove that error and nothing works.

I removed bower_components, npm packages, re-install all those packages again and that error is still there.

I am using Angular with AngularStrap and one component from Angular UI which is the accordion, but I am calling that component separately, not the full library.

Does someone here knows how to fix it ?

Comment: we need to see the code that is causing the issue, without it we could only guess at what is going on

Comment: @PatrickEvans I am expecting someone who had issues with the same error on the console.

Comment: How would they know they are having the same issue without seeing your code? For all they know you could be doing: `var obj; obj['ng-leave'];`